# Is Reflection in a base class a bad design idea?

Tags: c#, reflection, abstract-class

In general reflection in a base class can be put to some good and useful ends, but I have a case here where I'm between a rock and a hard place... Use Reflection, or expose public Factory classes when they really should be private semantically speaking (ie. not just anyone should be able to use them). I suppose some code is in order here:

```
public abstract class SingletonForm<TThis> : Form 
    where TThis : SingletonForm<TThis>
{
    private static TThis m_singleton;
    private static object m_lock = new object();
    private static ISingletonFormFactory<TThis> m_factory;

    protected SingletonForm() { }

    public static TThis Singleton
    {
        get
        {
            lock (m_lock)
            {
                if (m_factory == null)
                {
                    foreach (Type t in typeof(TThis).GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.NonPublic))
                    {
                        foreach (Type i in t.GetInterfaces())
                        {
                            if (i == typeof(ISingletonFormFactory<TThis>))
                                m_factory = (ISingletonFormFactory<TThis>)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
                        }
                    }

                    if (m_factory == null)
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                            "{0} does not implement a nested ISingletonFormFactory<{0}>.",
                            typeof(TThis).ToString()));
                }

                if (m_singleton == null || m_singleton.IsDisposed)
                {
                    m_singleton = m_factory.GetNew();
                }

                return m_singleton;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this code works for me, but is it a horrible kludge and/or a really bad idea? The other option is passing in the Factory's type as a type paramater, but then due to visiblity limitations, the Factory class must be public which means anyone can call it to make instances when they shouldn't be.

Comment: It would help if you said what this was trying to accomplish. And, BTW, you might help yourself by checking for null before you lock in addition to checking afterward.

Comment: This will hint at what I'm trying to get at, but have a look here at the "Third version" and tell me what you think: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Comment: edited to include my actual class

Comment: @monoxide: I know about test/lock/test, but what are you doing with Reflection is what I meant!

Comment: You mean testing if m_lock is null? Will that ever happen?

Comment: @monoxide: and why did you stop at step 2? You'll be locking every time that Singleton is referenced.

Comment: @monoxide: no, testing if m_factory is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with generics, you frequently have to use reflection. In that regard I think you're fine.

That said, I see two forms of code smell here. They may be due to code sanitation, however, so I'll just comment on them:

First, your static property is of a generic item. I'm 99.999% sure this will not even compile. If it does, it's bad form.

Second, you appear are returning a new instance for every call to `Bar`. This is also considered bad form for a getter. I would instead have a method called CreateBar() or something similar.

Comment: updated with actual code. Second is due to sanitisation. For the first one, are you refering to m_singleton, or m_lock?

Comment: I must lead a sheltered life. I've never needed to use Reflection with generics. Among other things, I would argue that code like in the question is not as maintainable as it should be. You restrict yourself to the code being maintained by developers who understand Reflection, and I'm not sure what you gain in return for that.

Comment: Single instance forms that don't give me a headache. This is more personal project than anything (for the moment atleast)

Comment: I thought abstracting this particular piece of functionality to an abstract base class would let me use it in different projects since alot of my personal projects are apps that operate out of the system tray with Application.Run() and single instance forms rather than application.Run(form)

Comment: @monoxide: My suggestion: "don't do that". You've produced a mess that i would never allow into production code. I bet if you try living without this, you'll find a better way to avoid cutting and pasting. You need to get a better feel for the nature of the variation among your different projects. _Then_ address the variation once you understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is also better handled with custom attributes where you can explicitly define the type to use.

```
[AttributeUsage( AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false )]
public sealed class SingletonFactoryAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type FactoryType{get;set;}   
    public SingletonFormAttribute( Type factoryType )
    { 
        FactoryType = factoryType; 
    }
}
```

Your singleton property now becomes

```
public static TThis Singleton
{
    get
    {
        lock (m_lock)
        {
            if (m_factory == null)
            {
                var attr = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute( 
                               typeof( TThis ), 
                               typeof( SingletonFactoryAttribute ) ) 
                               as SingletonFactoryAttribute;

                if (attr == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "{0} does not have a SingletonFactoryAttribute.",
                        typeof(TThis).ToString()));

                m_factory = Activator.CreateInstance( attr.FactoryType );
            }

            if (m_singleton == null || m_singleton.IsDisposed)
            {
                m_singleton = m_factory.GetNew();
            }

            return m_singleton;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, my final solution was simply: m_singleton = Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType(), true); *headdesk*

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible, I'd try to avoid using reflection if you can get away with it.

To do this, you could try using an [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Factory_Pattern) to get around the problem of directly exposing a public factory type, depending on your situation.

The way the Wikipedia example puts it (in Java) is that you create a factory interface, which your factory class implements, then you have something in your code generate the factory you need and return it as the factory interface.

Another way of doing this would be to create an abstract class instead of an interface for your abstract factory, then create a static method within this abstract class for returning the type factory you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, the following can be reduced from

```
foreach (Type i in t.GetInterfaces())
{
    if (i == typeof(ISingletonFormFactory<TThis>))
        m_factory = (ISingletonFormFactory<TThis>)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
}
```

to

```
if( typeof( ISingletonFormFactory<TThis> ).IsAssignableFrom( t ) )
    m_factory = Activator.CreateInstance( t ) as ISingletonFormFactory<TThis>;
```